# interaction on each regressor

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction

I saw a working paper where the authors ran a human subject experiment with three treatments ($J, j \in 1, 2, 3$) and estimated the outcome variable with the following model:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (x_1 \times T_j) + \beta_1 (x_2 \times T_j) + \epsilon_{it}
$$

where $i$ indexes subjects and $t$ indexes period.

The motivation for this specification is twofold. First, the treatment settings were different enough to justify considering the effect of each independent variable as treatment-specific. Second, by pooling the data they "exploit the full variation in the data."

This seems weird. Why not just run one model per treatment? Do you really "exploit the full variation" when you only allow the independent variable to vary within a treatment?

EDIT: corrected spelling and grammar.

Comment: Could you add a reference to that paper?